# different image color in view pager

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-viewpager

In my app I am using view pager. The problem is the images are different althougt the images' background are the same. It appears diffenrent in emulator and HTC desire. I've checked with Galaxy S3 AVD, it is exactly the same! It may be resolution issue. 
Here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="47dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="55" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" />


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used `weight` because I need to add buttons after the `viewpager` inside other layouts you see above.

my image xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:scaleType="center"
      android:src="@drawable/plate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?
image:[image]